# fix cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined when using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

```
for(i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length; i++){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("contC")[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
};
```

Comment: `<=` ======> `<`

Comment: You should also save `document.getElementsByClassName("contC")` under a variable instead of running it twice and save the rain forrests.

Comment: Use `forEach` which would be more simpler

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you need `<` instead of `<=` in your for loop. If `document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length` is `5`, then `document.getElementsByClassName("contC")[5]` is `undefined`, `4` would be the last index.

This works fine:

```
for(i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length; i++){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("contC")[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
};
```

No need, however, to call `document.getElementsByClassName` twice:

```
const els = document.getElementsByClassName("contC")
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) { 
    els[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
}
```

or:

```
const els = document.getElementsByClassName("contC")
Array.from(els).forEach(e => e.innerHTML = "aaa")
```

Comment: while this is accurate., you might want to explain what you've change from OP's code in order to fix their problem. It is not obvious from your code.

Comment: Perhaps you could also do `document.querySelectorAll(".contC").forEach(c => ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The exit condition of your for loop is incorrect. You are checking whether or not the `i` variable is smaller **OR EQUALS** to the length of your array. But, since the array index starts at 0, the `array[array.length]` position does not exists ( it goes from 0 to `array.length - 1`. Hense why you are getting this error.

```
for(let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length; i++){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("contC")[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
};
```

Below is an improved version of you code. Here is what i've changed.

- I've use the `let` keyword in order to initialize the variable correctly.
- i've saved the HTML node into an array instead of ready the whole document at each iteration.
- I've removed the semi-colon after the closing bracket of the `for` loop as it is not necessary.

```
const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("contC");
for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){ 
    nodes[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterate from 0 to collection lenght. It is necessary to iterate to `document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length - 1` or change condition from `<=` to `<`
While condition is `<=` last element is out of range of collection. If collection has 4 elements indexes are 0...3, collection[4] is out of range

```js
for(i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName("contC").length - 1; i++){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("contC")[i].innerHTML = "aaa";
};
```

```html
<div class='contC'></div>
<div class='contC'></div>
<div class='contC'></div>
<div class='contC'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for of loop like:

```
for (let elem of document.getElementsByClassName("contC")) {
  elem.innerHTML = "aaa";
}
```